# Call back block inside UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks

I have a query. I wanted to perform some operation asynchronously, say downloading a big file from internet inside `UIViewController`.
I wrote a Method in delegate which takes request and block as parameter

```
-(void)downloadDataFromURL:(NSMutableURLRequest *)_request withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *, bool ))completionHandler{

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *_response, NSData *_data, NSError *_error)
 {
     completionHandler(_data, true);

 }];
```

}

In my `viewDidLoad` method looks like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[mainDelegate downloadDataFromURL:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]] withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *_data, bool isFinished)
 {
     //Processed only if we are inside memory. anyway there are many leaks when I load these class again
}];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.}
```

now there is back button which pop the view controller

```
- (IBAction)BackBtnClicked:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];}
```

So how can I detect if I have popped the controller from memory inside my completionHandler? Or how can I cancel the completionHandler from getting executed. 
Because if I don't there will be leaks.

Comment: basically you want to cancel the `sendAsynchronousRequest` call?

Comment: its just example.. I am implementing a Class where I will just a pass Url and completion block for callBack which will execute when that task complete

Comment: Ok that fine, so basically you can use NSOperation and find last object from that queue and cancel the request. Like this.
`NSOperation *lastOp = [self.downloadQ.operations lastObject];
    [lastOp cancel];`

Comment: check my edited question

Comment: inside your completionHandler you can use  : to check if your VC is stil in the view:          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (weakSelf.view.window) {
                    
                  
                    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];

                }

        }];

Comment: is these correct way to create weakSelf? __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;